# Intersecting curves with angles at intersection points

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Problem statement:

Consider the two curves $(x,y)=(t^2,t+1), t\in{R}$ and $g(x,y)=5x^2+5xy+3y^2-8x-6y+3=0$
Find all intersecting points and (if they exist) the angles between the two intersecting curves.

**My solution**

I find the correct intersecting points but the angle I get for the first intersecting point should be the second and vice versa.

To find the intersecting points we substitute x(t) and y(t) from curve 1 into curve 2 above.
$$5t^4+5t^2(t+1)+3(t+1)^2-8t^2-6(t+1)+3=0 \iff t^3(t+1)=0$$
$$t_1=0, t_2=-1$$
$$P_1=(x_1,y_1)=(0,1), P_2=(x_2,y_2)=(1,0)$$
So far so good. Now about the angles. The first curve will have the direction
$$(x'(t), y'(t)) = (2t, 1)$$
The second curve will have the gradient
$$\nabla g=(10x+5y-8, 5x+6y-6)$$
$$\nabla g(x_i,y_i)\cdot(x'(t_i), y'(t_i)) = |\nabla g|\cdot|(x', y')|cos(\theta_i)$$

So for $P_1$ I get
$$t_1=0, (x_1,y_1)=(0,1)$$
$$(x'(0), y'(0)) = (0, 1)$$
$$\nabla g(0,1)=(-3,0)$$
$$\nabla g(0,1) \cdot (x'(0), y'(0)) = 0$$
$$\theta_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

For $P_2$ I get
$$t_2=-1, (x_{2}, y_{2})=(1,0)$$
$$(x'(-1), y'(-1)) = (-2, 1)$$
$$\nabla g(1,0)=(2, -1)$$
But these lines are parallel so
$$\theta_2=0$$

The correct answer should be the other way around, $\theta_1=0$ and $\theta_2=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Anyone can see what I have mixed up and/or what I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore this...

I just forgot that $\nabla g$ is the **normal** and not the **tangent**... Adjusting the normal to be in tangent form I get the proper results...